# API call function in useEffect creates infinite loop in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I have a Component where i'm maping an Array to render data. But before that, i need to call API taking id from each objects of the array to modify the array. Now, i am calling the API's in a function and calling the function in `useEffect()` . But when i do that, it continues to an infinite loop. Here's how my component looks like:

```js
const DemoComponent = (props) => {
    const [renderArr, setRenderArr] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getStatus();
      },[renderArr])


    const getStatus= async() =>{
        var arr = [
              {id: 1,name: Leather},
              {id: 2,name: Shoe},
              {id: 3,name: Belt},
            ]
      var firstStatus =  await API(arr[0].id , props.token)
      var secondStatus = await API(arr[1].id , props.token)
      var thirdStatus =  await API(arr[2].id , props.token)
      var statusObj = [
            { status: firstStatus.status },
            { status: secondStatus.status },
            { status: thirdStatus.status },
      ]
      var mergedArray = newArr.map((e, i) => ({ ...e, ...statusObj[i] }));
         setRenderArr(mergedArray);
      }
    }
    
    
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {mergedArray.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity>
                 <Text style={{ color: '#FFF' }}>{item.status}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        })}
    </View>
    );
};
```

Now, how can i stop this infinite loop. But in the meantime, i want to rerender when `renderArr` changes props.

Comment: You have side effect registered for `renderArr`, which calls a function that updates `renderArray`. Any change in `renderArr` will invoke the side effect and this loop goes on forever.

Comment: What is the solution for this @nithinpp

Comment: Simply remove the `renderArr` dependecny from your `useEffect`.  It will then only call only on component mount.

Answer (score 0):

Because you trigger the `renderArr`. You should do one call only when the component is mounted such as below snippet.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getStatus();
}, []);
```

Comment: Did this but still no luck @d3vma

Answer (score 0):

There are a few items I would like to point out here,

1. You have side effect registered for `renderArr`, which calls a function that updates `renderArr`. Any change in `renderArr` will invoke the side effect and this loop goes on forever.
2. Inside the `getStatus` function, you are updating your `renderArr` state after your application logic. But the `render` part is referring to some other variable `mergedArray`. You will have to change it to `renderArr` state.

```js
const DemoComponent = (props) => {
    
    const [renderArr, setRenderArr] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getStatus();
    },[]); // removed dependency to call it only once, (on mount)


    const getStatus= async() =>{
         ....

         setRenderArr(mergedArray); // state is updated with the new processed value
    }
    
    
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {renderArr.map((item, index) => { // changed to the state variable
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity>
                 <Text style={{ color: '#FFF' }}>{item.status}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        })}
    </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue unfortunately. Seems like just doing this: setRenderArr(mergedArray) lets it go for an infinite loop @nithinpp

Comment: Have you removed the dependency from `useEffect`?

Comment: Yes i did. @nithinpp

Comment: From the code I posted above, I don't see a reason for that to happen. Can you check if you have anything else that the code in my answer?

Comment: Yes just doing setRenderArr(mergedArray) in getStatus function is doing that. I don't see any other reason. Maybe the API requests are initializing or don't know. @nithinpp

Comment: can you setup a reproducible snack/codesandbox or anything?